# I can't get the user in django templates

Tags: python, django

I already saw all the links on stackoverflow related to this.
I am using Django 1.9.7 an I try to see in template if theuser is authenticated but I can't get the user.

Template code which is not printing anything:

```
{{ user.is_authenticate }}
{{ request.user.is_authenticate }}
```

Settings code:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I already tried withou social.apps and still not working, any ideas?

Comment: `user.is_authenticate` vs `user.is_authenticated`?

Comment: nope, I can't get even the username.

Comment: request is None and the user is None i think, because they are not printing anything.

Comment: You need to show us the view.

Comment: Are you using `RequestContext` (or `render`) or `Context` (or `render_to_response` with no custom context)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you pass the request context in the view, it's what adds the user to the context...

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def some_view(request):
  form = None
  # request.user accesses user here
  return render_to_response('some_template.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now in the template you can use:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}{{ request.user.email }}{% endif %}
```